# Чем отображать pdf на web странице?

Tags: flash, pdf, php, html

Подскажите чем отображать pdf на web странице с возможностью листания.
Пример http://issuu.com/

Comment: Мы используем стандартный вьювер от гугл, через iframe, вполне нормально работает. А вообще когда думали в сторону либы PDF.js от мозилла, но не было времени разбираться с ней тогда

Comment: Немного перефразирую. Нужно именно красиво и презентабильно, чтобы отображалось на сайте с возможностью пролистывания. Просто тупо открыть pfd - это не вариант. Крупная фирма хочет, можно предлагать платные недорогие решения.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходим следующий плагин Dirtysuds Embed PDF http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dirtysuds-embed-pdf/. Он использует стандартный просмотрщик гугл.

```
[еmbed]http://васяпупкин.рф/mypdf.pdf[/еmbed]
```

Как то так.

Ниже сам плагин на php:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dirtysuds_embed_pdf_enable_embeds' );
wp_embed_register_handler( 'pdf', '#(^(http|wpurl)\:\/\/.+\.pdf$)#i', 'dirtysuds_embed_pdf' );
add_shortcode( 'gdoc', 'dirtysuds_embed_pdf' );

function dirtysuds_embed_pdf_enable_embeds() {
    update_option('embed_autourls',1);
}

function dirtysuds_embed_pdf( $matches, $atts, $url, $rawattr=null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'height' => get_option('embed_size_h'),
        'width' => get_option('embed_size_w'),
        'border' => '0',
        'style' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'class' => 'pdf',
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    if (!strstr($url,'http://') && strstr($atts,'http://')) {
        $url = $atts;
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'height' => get_option('embed_size_h'),
            'width' => get_option('embed_size_w'),
            'border' => '0',
            'style' => '',
            'title' => '',
            'class' => 'pdf',
            'id' => '',
        ), $matches ) );
    }

    $embed = '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='.urlencode($url).'&amp;embedded=true" class="'.$class.'"';
    if ($id) {
        $embed .= ' id="'.$id.'"';
    }

    $embed .= ' frameborder="'.$border.'"';
    if ($border != '0') {
        $border .= 'px';
    }

    if ($style) {
        $embed .= ' style="height:'.$height.'px;width:'.$width.'px;border:'.$border.';'.$style.'"';
    } else {
        $embed .= ' style="height:'.$height.'px;width:'.$width.'px;border:'.$border.'"';
    }
    if ($title) {
        $embed .= ' title="'.$title.'"';
    }
    $embed .= ' width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"></iframe>';

    $embed  = '<![if !IE]>'.$embed.'<![endif]>';

    $embed .= '<!--[if IE]>'.
        '<object width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" type="application/pdf" data="'.$url.'" class="'.$class.' ie"';

    if ($id) {
        $embed .= ' id="'.$id.'"';
```

Comment: необходим, это громко сказано.